# Populating DropdownList from AJAX (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have dropdown list in my view

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Question1", null, "Вопрос 1", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control", @style = "height:40px;margin-bottom: 20px;"})
```

I have AJAX call that display all questions

Here it is

```
 function question_update() {
    $(".count").empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("QuestionsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var email = result;
            var edit = '@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")';
            var delete_ = '@Url.Content("~/Images/Delete.png")';
            // console.log(result[0].Name);
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                var arrow  = '@Url.Content("~/Images/plus_plus.png")';
                var questionHtml = '<div class = "title" style="margin-top:15px;margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:10px;">'
                    +
                    '<img class="click" src="'
                    + arrow
                    + '">' +
                    '<span class="test">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="testclass" readonly value="' +
                    result[i].Quest + '">' +
                    '<a style="margin-left:25px;">' +
                    '<img src="' + edit + '"/>' +
                    '<img style="margin-left:10px;" src="' + delete_ + '"/>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class ="content" style="margin-left:60px; width: 80%; height: 100px; background: white;">' +
                    '<div style="width: 100%">' +
                    '<div style="float:left; width: 50%;">' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 40px;">' + "Время на ответ"  + '</b>' +
                    '<b>' + ":" + '</b>' +
                    '<span>' + "Время на подготовку" +'</span>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div style="float:right; width: 50%;">' +
                    '<b>' + result[i].TimeForAnswer + '</b>' +
                    '<b>' + ":" + '</b>' +
                    '<b>' + result[i].TimeForReady + '</b>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                $(".count").append(questionHtml);
```

At sucess of it I need to update values in dropdown

I make it like this

```
  function question_update() {
    $(".count").empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("QuestionsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var email = result;
            var edit = '@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")';
            var delete_ = '@Url.Content("~/Images/Delete.png")';
            // console.log(result[0].Name);
            for (var i = 0; i <= email.length - 1; i++) {
                var arrow  = '@Url.Content("~/Images/plus_plus.png")';
                var questionHtml = '<div class = "title" style="margin-top:15px;margin-left:15px;margin-bottom:10px;">'
                    +
                    '<img class="click" src="'
                    + arrow
                    + '">' +
                    '<span class="test">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="testclass" readonly value="' +
                    result[i].Quest + '">' +
                    '<a style="margin-left:25px;">' +
                    '<img src="' + edit + '"/>' +
                    '<img style="margin-left:10px;" src="' + delete_ + '"/>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class ="content" style="margin-left:60px; width: 80%; height: 100px; background: white;">' +
                    '<div style="width: 100%">' +
                    '<div style="float:left; width: 50%;">' +
                    '<b style="margin-left: 40px;">' + "Время на ответ"  + '</b>' +
                    '<b>' + ":" + '</b>' +
                    '<span>' + "Время на подготовку" +'</span>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div style="float:right; width: 50%;">' +
                    '<b>' + result[i].TimeForAnswer + '</b>' +
                    '<b>' + ":" + '</b>' +
                    '<b>' + result[i].TimeForReady + '</b>'+
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                $(".count").append(questionHtml);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action(" QuestionsList_new", "Questions")',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        var $vacancy = $("#Question1");
                        $vacancy.empty();
                        $.each(result, function (a, b) {
                            $vacancy.append('<option value="' + b.Value + '">' + b.Text + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But I don't see any updates in DropdownList.

Where is my problem?

**UPDATE**

All okay. But I have new problem. In my dropdownlist I have `undefined`.

```html
<select class="form-control" id="Question1" name="Question1" style="height:40px;margin-bottom: 20px;"><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option><option value="undefined">undefined</option></select>
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: Try using `$vacancy.append($('<option value="' + b.Value + '">' + b.Text + '</option>'));`

Comment: Check to see if $vacancy exists in DOM after ajax success.

Comment: check dom i want to know value of $("#Question1").innerHtml()

Comment: I update my post@Rush.2707

Comment: I update my post@User3250

Comment: I would suggest that the structure of `result` is not what you expect. Can you show the JSON that's returned by the ajax please?

Comment: `[0] { ID = 1048, Quest = "тест" }` 

@ADyson

Comment: so you can clearly see that the properties `b.Value` and `b.Text` that you're trying to access don't exist in that data. `b.ID` and `b.Quest` should work.

Comment: That's works, thank's@ADyson

Comment: @Logan no problem. I have added it as the full answer, if it has helped you please consider upvoting and/or marking as accepted - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample data you gave for the `result` variable coming back from the server:

```
{ ID = 1048, Quest = "тест" }
```

your .each loop needs to look like this:

```
$.each(result, function (a, b) {
  $vacancy.append('<option value="' + b.ID + '">' + b.Quest + '</option>');
});
```

The properties "text" and "value" that you were trying to access don't exist in the data, hence why you were getting "undefined". You need to use the names of the actual properties involved.